# Is there any way, to get specific columns from DATA JPA , using @Query annotation in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am Using JPARespository to perform Database operations. I have a requirement, where I want to select specific columns from given table while passing a few where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections). Spring Data will select only required columns. It works with both generated queries from method name and `@Query` annotation.

Related question: [Spring Data JPA Projection selected fields from the DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194614/spring-data-jpa-projection-selected-fields-from-the-db)